# Help with 2nd Law and irreversibilty

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, entropy, reversibility

This question is about the seemingly idealized notion of isolated systems and truly irreversible processes in the context of the 2nd Law.

Here are the definitions and citations I'll use then my question (**mostly focused on d**):

a)

"Consider an isolated system. The second law says that any process that would reduce the entropy of the isolated system is impossible. **Suppose a process takes place within the isolated system in what we shall call the forward direction. If the change in state of the system is such that the entropy increases for the forward process, then for the backward process (that is, for the reverse change in state) the entropy would decrease. The backward process is therefore impossible, and we therefore say that the forward process is irreversible."**

b)

"Entropy is produced in irreversible processes. **All real processes (with the possible exception of superconducting current flows) are in some measure irreversible**, though many processes can be analyzed quite adequately by assuming that they are reversible"

c)

"**Processes that are irreversible include:**
Movement with friction
Unrestrained expansion
Energy transfer as heat due to large temperature non uniformities
Electric current flow through a non zero resistance
Spontaneous chemical reaction
Mixing of matter of different composition or state.
"

https://web.mit.edu/16.unified/www/FALL/thermodynamics/notes/node51.html&ved=2ahUKEwj_vs6oh8_oAhXWuZ4KHb9wASIQFjAKegQIBRAB&usg=AOvVaw1_1izuzZuu4GQpIY5U2q30

d)

"**If the initial states can be restored by any means whatever, the process is by definition completely reversible.**"

e)
"**Reversible processes are idealizations not actually encountered.**"

https://web.mit.edu/16.unified/www/SPRING/propulsion/notes/node37.html#SECTION05224000000000000000

I guess the crux of my question depends on d), that if you can restore a system *by any means* to its previous state, it's reversible. It doesn't even have to be along the same path backwards, just any means. Well what about the CPT theorem? I thought the laws of physics are entirely symmetric with respect to the CPT theorem, and that any process' complete inverse is valid, thus we have path back to our original state?

Ok but we live in an expanding universe so there is no perfect inverted path right, thus losing that guarantee of satisfying d). However, doesn't the observable universe have a horizon that "puts us in a finite box" so to speak (https://youtu.be/jhnKBKZvb_U?t=41m20s). And doesn't the recurrence theorem mean this finite horizon guarantees we will pass back through every previous state?

So we satisfy d) and thus once again we are left looking for a truly irreversible process. So what is one? The ones in c) seem to suffer from all the problems above, especially with the notion isolated systems are also an idealization.

Comment: "I guess the crux of my question depends on d), that if you can restore a system by any means to its previous state, it's reversible." That's not what d) says. It says if the initial STATES can be restored..."   It's not just the initial state of the system, but also the surroundings, for the process to be reversible.

Comment: So the entire observable universe must get back to its previous state? @BobD They really glossed over that if that's the case. I think the overall question holds though (at least Susskind thinks so in the youtube link?), recurrence would just take much much longer

Comment: Yes that is correct. Not sure what you mean by "recurrence would just take much longer", but if you are referring to the need to carry out the process quasi-statically, then yes, it would take infinitely long to for the process to go forward and reverse in order to be reversible.

Comment: Are you invoking the one-shot universe then, that we wont recur because our universe is open/expanding? Susskind claims otherwise in the video link in the question. @BobD

Comment: I'm not talking about an "expanding universe", just basic thermodynamics. I'm saying in thermodynamics one defines the system and  the nature of the system boundaries (open, closed, isolated). By default everything outside the system is the surroundings. The system + surroundings is the "universe" if you will. Are you familiar with the Carnot Cycle? It is a reversible cycle that when complete both the system and the surroundings return to their original state.  I'm sorry that about all the time I have for this. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Bringing CPT theorem into this question and the expansion of the universe, seams to me as watering the question down. Hence, I will instead focus on your statement a:

> If the change in state of the system is such that the entropy
>   increases for the forward process, then [...] the
>   backward process is [...] **impossible** [...]

Unfortunately, this statement is **incorrect**. In order to see this, let's consider a simple example. Let's assume we have a volume which is separated into two compartments. While in the first compartment we have an ideal gas, the second compartment is empty. If we open a "door" between the two compartment at time $t_0$ the gas will spread out until it homogeneously occupies both compartments. This homogeneous state is the state of thermal equilibrium. Let's say it is reached after time $t_1$. Now we can ask, is it **possible** that the system reverses this process at time $t_2 > t_1$? The answer is yes, it is possible. However, it is "very" improbable.

The key point is, that there is nothing in the law of physics which prevents a macroscopic system to occupy a non-equilibrium state. In contrast, one of the basic laws of thermodynamics (I can never remember which one) states, that every allowed micro-state if occupied with the same probability. Hence, if we check the micro-state and find that the system is in a state, which belongs to an homogeneous distribution of the gas in both compartments, this particular micro-state is not more probable  than the initial state. However, there exists many more states which are close to equilibrium than there are states which are far from equilibrium. Therefore, although it is possible, it is extremely improbable that the gas gathers in one compartment.

Comment: Thank you, what you are saying about reversing entropy being possible just unlikely makes more sense so I wonder why the MIT link worded that part such. I bring in the greater universe because I want to understand why we don't see **recurrences**  if entropy reversal is at least *possible*. Susskind's youtube link above says we would expect them even in an expanding universe. (his out is the multiverse) So am I to take away that we should expect a recurrence in the future? Why don't we naively assume the big bang was such a recurrence then? CPT violated that quote too which is why I included.